# beamer: How to play movies in their original size?

Tags: beamer, movie15, media9, multimedia

When using the [`multimedia`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/base/multimedia) package with the [`beamer`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/beamer) class, you must specify the width and height of the movie like this:

```
\movie[width=8.0cm,height=8.0cm]{}{movie.avi}
```

The problem is that the video loses quality due to resizing.

How do I make beamer show the video in its original size, i.e. the same size as when I play it in VLC or Media Player?

I tried putting the size of the video in pixels like this:

```
\movie[width=600px,height=600px]{}{movie.avi}
```

But `beamer` displayed it much bigger than it should.

Answer (score 3):

With the `media9` package and Adobe Reader you can play video files in a detached window at their natural size. You need to know the video size in pixels and pass it as an argument to the `windowed` option, e. g.:

```
\usepackage{media9}
...

\includemedia[
   windowed=480x360,
   addresource=myvid.mp4,
   flashvars={source=myvid.mp4,autoPlay=true}
]{\strut Click!}{VPlayer.swf}
```

(Replace `myvid.mp4` with your video file, which must be in the H.264 format.)